# Survey Data Model

Tags: database, data-modeling, survey

I'm developing a simple survey module for an ASP application I'm working on and I'd like to get some suggestions on the data model.

Questions can be one of  three types - multiple choice, multiple answer; multiple choice, single answer, and free response.

I'm thinking of the following tables:

1. Question - with a question type discriminator ifeld
2. PossibleAnswers- with a questionID and answer text field
3. SurveyQuestionResponse- with a questionID, a clientID, and answer text

Am I making this too simple?

Comment: [not a true duplicate question,but] do check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482201/database-design-for-general-web-form/ for some ideas.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the
     [**Data Model library at databaseanswers.org**](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm)
Models #76 thru #81 seem pertinent, if only for "inspiration".

A lot depends on the level of sophistication of the surveys you manage, as some surveys in particular dynamic ones (aimed at removing some of the bias) require additional fields for storing properties such as the probabilities with which a particular question (or reply) is used, the many forms of a question and associated probability, and also the recording of the questions and suggested replies that were effectively offered for a give surveyee.

The model the above link:

[image]

Comment: as of 1/31/10 they're #81 - #84

Comment: The answer above references the "questionnaires" series on the website.