# How to design a static/dynamic survey application?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I'm struggling here a lot really.

I need to prepare a form that is something between static and dynamic.
Basically on the first part of the survey you get a question asking you to select items from the checklist. You select the items and then you are presented with a list of n number of questions.

Now, some facts:

- the questions and possible answers for those don't change or change so rarely it's irrelevant.
- 90% if questions have the same possible answers (example below)
- there's somewhere between 10 and 30 questions

Most questions look like this:

```
X. This product is high quality stuff.
```

Possible answers are (only one to be selected, which leaves me with select or radios):

```
1. Strongly agree  
2. Agree  
3. etc.  // (you know the pattern...)
```

There is few odd questions that the person filling the form need to answer by writing something into `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`

Now, depending on the how many items were selected in the first question the form is generated like this:

```
       X. Question:
Item1: <select> for Item1
Item2: <select> for Item2
etc.
```

or

```
       X. Question:
Item1: <textarea> for Item1
Item2: <textarea> for Item2
etc.
```

Also, questions are grouped into parts. All displayed on the same page, but separated visually with each group having it's own header/title.

Now. My first approach was to create several tables in database. Items, QuestionGroups, QuestionTypes, Questions and QuestionOptions (this would store the Agree/Disagree strings).

I feel this is somewhat very troublesome approach for such a simple task. There are no plans in any foreseeable future in modifying the form (will be reused on a regular basis).

The results from this survey will be counted and output to a chart.

Any ideas on easier approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to go with the multiple tables etc. design, the following StackOverflow questions may provide ideas and insight

- [**survey data model**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651849/survey-data-model)
- [**database design for general web form**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482201/database-design-for-general-web-form)